# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\display_discount.php on line 13

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP this semester and I'm both enjoying it and immediately lost a bit on my first real assignment. There are a few other similar questions but, because I'm new, I'm not able to extrapolate their answers to help with this.

I am getting the error in the title. The mission is to create POST code to handle all of the product description, price data, etc. I've added that code, but I'm getting the must be a string error on like 13 (under product description) but am unsure why.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Product Discount Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>This page is under construction</h1>

        <label>Product Description:</label>
        <span><?php echo $product_description = $_POST('product_desc'); ?></span><br /> (THIS IS LINE 13)

        <label>List Price:</label>
        <span><?php echo $list_price_formatted = $_POST('list_price'); ?></span><br />

        <label>Standard Discount:</label>
        <span><?php echo $discount_percent_formatted = $_POST('std_discount'); ?></span><br />

        <label>Discount Amount:</label>
        <span><?php echo $discount_formatted= $_POST('discount_amt'); ?></span><br />

        <label>Discount Price:</label>
        <span><?php echo $discount_price_formatted = $_POST('final_price'); ?></span><br />

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the error is in line 13, please [only give line 13](http://sscce.org/) or indicate which is. You're expecting us to help, then don't expect us to count to 13.

Comment: Understood. I did write THIS IS LINE 13 in there but I'll try to make it more obvious in the future.

Comment: Hmm didn't even see that since it was scrolled out of the side. Add a `<!-- the next line is 13 -->` HTML comment above it or so next time  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` is not a function but an array. Functions are invoked with parameters between parentheses, arrays are queried with square brackets. Thus:

```
 $_POST('product_desc')
```

should be:

```
 $_POST['product_desc']
```

Comment: Sure enough, this was my eyesight letting me down. In my textbook, looked like () not []. I feel pretty dumb but thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

using `$_POST[...]` for get post data not `$_POST(...)`